# Joomla 3.6 to 3.7 Article Options Missing

Tags: joomla

I recently upgraded from Joomla 3.6 to 3.7. In doing so, I've lost the options in my Articles. For example, "Images and Links" is not appearing.

[Image of Article Edit Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7nsC.png)

I have checked to see if its a backend thing and these are my current settings:
[Image of Backend Settings for Articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRYGM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try:

- set error reporting to maximum in Global Configuration
- check JavaScript Console for any meaningful errors
- try clearing Joomla cache
- try [clearing your local web browser cache](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_clear_cache_in_firefox_internetexplorer_safari_opera)
- try an alternative browser (e.g. FireFox if you are using Chrome or vice versa)
- try alternative administration template (e.g. Hathor if you are using Isis or vice versa)
- try alternative editor e.g. TinyMCE
- run a backup and try reinstalling core files via Joomla Update component
- upgrade all third party extensions to the latest versions
- try disabling third party plugins one by one and check if this makes any difference

Comment: Thanks for the reply Neil, but it looks like that didn't work either.

Comment: OK, I have added some more things to try to help narrow down the issue